# Scraping website with BS4 // accessing class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am tring to extract different information from websites with BeautifulSoup, such as title of the product and the price.

I do that with different urls, looping through the urls with `for...in...`. Here, I'll just provide a snippet without the loop.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

url= 'https://www.mediamarkt.ch/fr/product/_lg-oled65gx6la-1991479.html'

html_content = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")

price = soup.find('meta', property="product:price:amount")
title = soup.find("div", {"class": "flix-model-name"})
title2 = soup.find('div', class_="flix-model-name")
title3 = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "flix-model-name"})

print(price['content'])
print(title)
print(title2)
print(title3)
```

So from this URL https://www.mediamarkt.ch/fr/product/_lg-oled65gx6la-1991479.html I wasnt to extract the product number. the only place I find it is in the div `class="flix-model-name"`. However, I am totally unable to reach it. I tried different ways to access it in the `title`, `title2`, `title3`, but I always have the output `none`.

I am a bit of a beginner, so I guess I am probably missing something basic... If so, please pardon me for that.

Any help is welcome! Many thanks in advance!

just for info, with each url I thought of appending the data and write them on a CSV file like that:

```py
for url in urls:
    html_content = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
    row=[]
    try:
        # title = YOUR VERY WELCOMED ANSWER
        prices = soup.find('meta', property="product:price:amount")
        row = (title.text+','+prices['content']+'\n')
        data.append(row)
    except:
        pass

file = open('database.csv','w')
i = 0
while i < (len(data)):
    file.write(data[i])
    i +=1
file.close()
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

David

Comment: I believe the content you are looking for is being loaded by JavaScript code (i.e. AJAX) after the main document is loaded and that is why you do not find the elements you are looking for in the downloaded page. I believe you will need to either use a tool such as Selenium to drive a browser and get the content from that or analyze the JavaScript fetch requests being made after the page is loaded using a browser inspector to figure out what URL's you would need to request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below approach using python - [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) simple, straightforward, reliable, fast and less code is required when it comes to requests. I have fetched the API URL from website itself after inspecting the network section of google chrome browser.

What exactly below script is doing:

First it will take the API URL, create the URL based on 2 dynamic parameters(product and category) and then do GET request to get the data.

After getting the data script will parse the JSON data using json.loads library.
Finally, it will iterate all over the list of products one by one and print the details which are divided in 2 categotries '**box1_ProductToProduct**' and '**box2_KategorieTopseller**' like Brand, Name, Product number and Unit price. Same way you can add more details by looking in to the API call.

```
import json
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def scrap_product_details():
PRODUCT = 'MMCH1991479' #Product number
CATEGORY = '680942' #Category number
URL = 'https://www.mediamarkt.ch/rde_server/res/MMCH/recomm/product_detail/sid/WACXyEbIf3khlu6FcHlh1B1?product=' + PRODUCT + '&category=' + CATEGORY  # dynamic URL
response = requests.get(URL,verify = False) #GET request to fetch the data
result = json.loads(response.text) # Parse JSON data using json.loads
box1_ProductToProduct = result[0]['box1_ProductToProduct'] # Extracted data from API
box2_KategorieTopseller = result[1]['box2_KategorieTopseller']

for item in box1_ProductToProduct: # loop over extracted data
    print('-' * 100)
    print('Brand : ',item['brand'])
    print('Name : ',item['name'])
    print('Net Unit Price : ',item['netUnitPrice'])
    print('Product Number : ',item['product_nr'])
    print('-' * 100)

for item in box2_KategorieTopseller:  # loop over extracted data
    print('-' * 100)
    print('Brand : ',item['brand'])
    print('Name : ',item['name'])
    print('Net Unit Price : ',item['netUnitPrice'])
    print('Product Number : ',item['product_nr'])
    print('-' * 100)

scrap_product_details()
```

Comment: Whow, that's impressive. I kind of understant what the steps, but I won't be much able to modify it.

As I've understood, the script takes all the TVs which are labbelled as "TopSeller". Is there a way to catch all the TVs from the website?

Again, many thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case you have to first check the URL where all the TV’s are listed and then give it a try. If that works for you please accept and upvote my answer this help me motivated. Thanks

Comment: Allright, Ill try this.

Many thanks for your help!